# Probability of each player scores at least once in a simple random game

Tags: probability

Let’s suppose a very simple game that lasts 3 seconds only.

A player generates a random number between 1 and 3 in the first second.
If the generated number is equal to 3, the player scores and s(he) generates a new random number for the next second.
Otherwise, the generated number is incremented for the next second.
For example, the player generated 2 in the first second. In the next second, the generated value will be incremented to 3 and the player scores and a new value is generated for the last second. 
In the best case, the player generated 3  every second.
The worst case is when the player generates 1 at the first second (the player scores just once in the last second)

Let’s suppose two players are playing this game.
There is a special rule when there are multiple players. 
If both have value 3 at the same time, no one scores.
For instance,  when both players generate 1 in the first second, they will have the value 3 in the last second at the same time.

What is the probability that both players score at least once during these 3 seconds of game?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "number" you mean *natural number"?  What about $2.7664455519$?  If so, the chance that the player chooses $3$ is $0$.

Comment: What happens if e.g. both players generate a 3 in first round? They do not score then, but I guess the 3 will not be incremented (correct me if I am wrong). Do both generate a new number then?

Comment: If they generate 3 in the first round they don't score. They generate a new number for the next round.

Comment: How about first two rounds both generate 2? Will this score and leave 1 OR no score?

Comment: Hi, in this case the value would be 3 in the second round, no score, but they would have  one last opportunity in generating a 3 (one of them) in the last round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let $A$, $B$ and $O$ denote player $A$ scoring, player $B$ scoring and no one scoring, respectively, then the admissible patterns for the three seconds are $AAB$, $ABA$, $BAA$, $ABO$, $AOB$, $OAB$, and the corresponding patterns with $A$ and $B$ swapped. We can calculate the probability for each of them to occur. Here are the numbers that need to be generated (with $\overline3$ denoting “not a $3$” and an empty cell indicating that the player doesn't generate a number in that round):

\begin{array}{c|cccccc|c}
&A_1&A_2&A_3&B_1&B_2&B_3&\text{probability}\\\hline
AAB&3&3&\overline3&1&&&\frac2{81}\\
ABA&3&2&&2&&\overline3&\frac2{81}\\
BAA&2&&3&3&1&&\frac1{81}\\
ABO&3&1&&2&&\overline3&\frac2{81}\\
AOB&3&1&&1&&&\frac1{27}\\
OAB&2&&\overline3&1&&&\frac2{27}
\end{array}

We need to add up all these probabilities and multiply by $2$ for the possibility of swapping $A$ and $B$, so the total probability that both players score at least once is

$$
2\left(\frac2{81}+\frac2{81}+\frac1{81}+\frac2{81}+\frac3{81}+\frac6{81}\right)=\frac{32}{81}=\frac{2^5}{3^4}\approx39.5\%\;.
$$